# If, else-if, and else statements inside a "case" for a switch-case-break statement?

Tags: c, case, break, if-statement

I know the syntax for writing a case break statement, but I'm wondering if this is allowed:

CODE:

```
    case 'p':
    {
    printf("Give number: ");
    scanf("%d, &int_1);
    if int_1=5;{
    printf("Played: you win");
    }
    break;
    }
```

Basically I'm just wondering if this is something that's possible to do, I know the code is incomplete but I don't want anyone to think I'm trying to elicit specific answers. I simply seek a better understanding of applying conditionals to my programs. Thank you.

EDIT: Other than in the tags, I didn't specify so just in case this isn't clear, this is in C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you can nest an `if` inside of `swtich`/`case` statement (or vice versa). If you want to badly enough, you could have a loop containing a `switch` containing several `if`s, etc.

Bottom line: the limit on nesting various kinds of statements is normally imposed by such considerations as taste and readability, not limitations built into the language.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's allowed. But you also forgot the `(`parentheses`)` around your `if`:

```
if int_1=5;{
```

should be:

```
if (int_1 == 5){
```

So if it wasn't compiling, this is the reason.

Comment: It was compiling, even with -gcc -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic-errors. Should it not have?

Comment: I've never seen an if-statement used without the parentheses. If it compiled for you (it didn't for me), then maybe it's an old ansi thing that they eventually took out.

Comment: glad you understood what i meant, i was talking about the level of warnings haha. thanks. what compiler are you using? curious

Comment: VS2010 C++ compiler. So perhaps it's a C-only thing or a GCC extension. It just outright errored on me.